# Use SendKeys with variable vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code for every letter of the alphabet in the sub `WorkBook_Open`:

`Application.OnKey "a", "'LetterPress ""a""'"`

Then in a different module I have a sub:
`Sub LetterPress(B as String)`

In the LetterPress sub there's a long If statement that closes with:

```
else
    Application.SendKeys(B)
End If
```

Basically, if none of the if statements trigger I just want to send the key, like if the OnKey command wasn't run.

It doesn't work though. It correctly enters the Else-part and `Application.SendKeys(B)` is run. But no letter is typed. How do I use SendKeys with a variable?

Comment: Why are you checking `OnKey` in `Workbook_Open`? That event only runs once when the workbook is first opened and should not catch any other keypress events.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, care to explain? I want the code to run when the workbook opens. Does this hinder SendKeys?

Comment: I'd imagine you get stuck in a recursive loop unless you turned off the `OnKey` somewhere in the `LetterPress` routine.

Comment: There's a more fundamental question I think, at least for my understanding:  what are you trying to achieve by catching and interpreting all the keystrokes? Do you intend to examine each keystroke in your code for the whole workbook or any/all operations? What are you trying to prevent, or feature you're trying to create?

Comment: Rory: Yes that must be it! PeterT: I'ts a search field, if you press "a" it enters a and then starts a macro that find all entries starting with an a. Then you might press "b" and then it finds all entries starting with ab. Like google, it suggests searchresults. It's for this workbook only. And only in specific cells. ```If Cell = A5 Then Call Search1(B) ElseIf Cell = A6 Then Call Search2(B) Else Application.SendKeys(B) End If``` is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If the active cells is a certain cell and you press a letter, call a sub, if it's any other cell, behave like normal (just type the letter like normal).